# SSRS Chart Calculated Series alongside a Regular Series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I've noticed that in SSRS the ability to add a calculated series disappears if you already have a field filled in for the "Series Groups" part of the graph. Screenshot to demonstrate:
[image]

However I need to be able to add some calculated trend lines for the data and obviously removing the Series group renders the chart useless. How do I go about getting a Series and a calculated series on a chart?

Comment: Is not it possible you add the series at T-SQL level? Share the query you have and how should be calculated the series. Also you can create a category group that includes the series group, share your dataset and details about the calculated series in order to see if there is a workaround to your issue.